# The license located at config/license.key belongs to X

Tags: license

I have an error appearing on my site:

[image]

This site is the production version of the site - before hand there was a staging version and a test version.

The test version (hosted on the same server, does not have this error).

So my question is how do I generate a new License? this is a solo version of craft btw not a pro.
I have deleted the license in config/license.key - hoping this would generate a new one and the problem would be over - a new license was generated but the message remains.

Any help would be great -
Thanks - W

Comment: Both answers below are good, so I won’t add a third. But you can tell Craft to “phone home” and check the license credentials when you “check for updates”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into Utilities > Caches > Clear Caches. I can't remember exactly which cache, but try all of them (maybe untick the asset transforms ones so you don't unnecessarily regenerate transformed assets).

Comment: Great shout to not re-set cache for images + pages as well

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's `Data Caches`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the license to your [Craft ID](https://id.craftcms.com) account, and update the URL it's attached to from there.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I think this would be best for pro versions but for solo versions it seems really odd to need to create a account and change the registered domain when all I should really need is to change the license - thanks